# Filter certain URL in Google Tag Manager 'Custom HTML' tags

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, mixpanel

I have a tag in Google Tag Manager that fires on a **click** event on a button. It then injects a `Custom HTML Tag` into my page. This is what I inject:

```
<script>
// This 'if' statement will check if this is a Google Crawler,
// and if not, continue.
if (document.location.href.search('.appspot.') == -1) {
  window.mixpanel = window.mixpanel || {};
  window.ga = window.ga || {};
  window['optimizely'] = window['optimizely'] || [];

  // Specifiek
  mixpanel.track('CTAMaakAfspraak');
  ga('send', 'event', 'CTAMaakAfspraak');
  window.optimizely.push(["trackEvent", "CTAMaakAfspraak"]);
}
</script>
```

As you can see, on line `4` I check if the current URL matches a certain string. If it doesn't (it returns `-1`), it will track some events.

The thing is, the events still show up in my live feed of MixPanel:

[image: Image showing the event that should be ignored. Note the 'Current URL' field.]

Note the Current URL field. It clearly contains `.appspot.`, which I search for.

Can someone explain why these happen at all, and how to avoid this behavior?

Edit: here are some screenshots depicting the problem.

**My tag**:

[image: My tag]

**My trigger**:

[image: My trigger]

**My variables**:

[image: My variables]

Comment: While I don't know why this is happening I suggest you do not do programming logic in the tag but rather add an exception to the rules that fire your tag (also your ga event has to few parameters, plus GTM assigns random tracker names so it will probably not fire when you use the default tracker).

Comment: I've added "`Page URL` does not contain .appspot." to the trigger "fire on:" field. Now we wait. Thanks for the suggestion, although I have a feeling this will not suffice.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your tags, variables, and triggers to help troubleshoot?

Comment: @EikePierstorff is spot on with some of his observations as well. Your GA event doesn't include the required "action", and also you cannot invoke `ga` calls without the specific GTM tracker name (so your event won't fire, or if it does, then it's doing incorrectly or the data is not reliable). A better option would be leave the logic to your triggers so instead of checking `document.location.href`, just do fire your tag only if the href doesn't include `.appspot.` or something like that.